# Unknown error parsing query

Tags: soql

in soql

```
Select Id,
       Name,
       PermissionsViewAllData, 
       PermissionsModifyAllData,
       Permissions Author Apex
From Profile
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Santosh! As is, you have provided a statement of a problem that you're encountering, but you haven't actually asked a question. In this case, I can guess that your question is along the lines of _why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?_ Please take the time to read [ask], and remember that showing some effort at researching your question before you ask it, and including an appropriate level of detail, tends to attract more attention (and better answers).

Answer (score 3):

Remove spaces from `Permissions Author Apex`

```
 Select Id,Name,PermissionsViewAllData, PermissionsModifyAllData,PermissionsAuthorApex From Profile
```